# Using paginate_links() to generate "1, 2, 3 ... 10, 20, 30, 40... 55" paginations

Tags: pagination

I found this code :

```
    // Get total number of pages
    global $wp_query;
    $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    // Only paginate if we have more than one page
    if ( $total > 1 )  {
         // Get the current page
         if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
              $current_page = 1;
         // Structure of “format” depends on whether we’re using pretty permalinks
        $permalinks = get_option('permalink_structure');
        $format = empty( $permalinks ) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';
        echo paginate_links(array(
              'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
              'format' => $format,
              'current' => $current_page,
              'total' => $total,
              'mid_size' => 2,
              'type' => 'list'
        ));
    }
```

It works ok but it generates pagination like "1, 2, 3 ... LASTPAGENUMBER", I've seen plugins that generate paginations like this "1, 2, 3... 19, 20, 30 ... LASTPAGENUMBER".

Can this be achieved using paginate_links() function?

I don't want to add a plugin just for this small tweak.

Answer (score 4):

The [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function does this by default. The controlling parameter is `mid_size`, which determines the number of page links **around the current page** to display. The default value is **`2`**.

What this means is that, assuming you have 12 pages, and the current page is **Page 1**, the pagination will look like:

```
1 2 3 ... 12
```

But if the current page is **Page 6**, the pagination will look like:

```
1 ... 4 5 6 7 8 ... 12
```

I could be mistaken, but I *think* that's how must pagination-link Plugins work.

#### Edit

Sorry, I misread your question at first, and didn't grasp that you want to output *every tenth page* in your pagination links.

This function doesn't have a built-in parameter to do what you want. Your best bet might be to set `'show_all'` to `true`, change `'type'` to `'array'`, and then construct the output yourself, by looping through the array values.

Answer (score 2):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

What you are looking for is 'end_size', add this to argument array with the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$args= new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'=>'card',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'paged' => $paged,
    ));  


    if($args->have_posts()) :

        while($args->have_posts())  : $args->the_post();

        $permalink=get_the_permalink(get_the_ID());
        $title=get_the_title();

        echo '<div class="col-md-4 card-details"><a href="'.$permalink.'">';
        echo '<div class="card-img">';the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="card-title"><h4>'.$title.'</h4></a>';
        echo'</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        endwhile;

        $total_pages = $args->max_num_pages;

        ?>

        <div class="greetings-pagination col-md-12">

        <?php

        if ($total_pages > 1){

            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));

            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format' => '/page/%#%',
                'current' => $current_page,
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'prev_text'    => __('prev'),
                'next_text'    => __('next'),
            ));
        }

    ?>  

    </div>

    <?php else :?>
    <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', ''); ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Just copy the code including top two lines & you will get pagination for custom post type that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress developer website it did mention some parameters.This is the [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) about this function.You can check 'end_size' for more information.

And I still got a question.I use `<?php echo paginate_links(); ?>` in my theme template and it works perfectly(As the picture shows).[image]

But I am not sure if it would cause some other problems.